# Should I register for one.alpha.example.com if I have alpha.example.com?

Tags: dns, webserver, domain-name

Say I have an IP registered with domain name `alpha.example.com`, and a server on this IP. Now I want to run multiple web sites on this server.

What should I do to serve `one.alpha.example.com` and `alpha.example.com` simultanesly? I know basic configuration on Apache/HTTPD, and what I need is to mapping `one.alpha.example.com` to same IP for `alpha.example.com`. Should I go through some registration procedures, or some configuration on that server is enough (setup something like `BIND`, or `resolve.conf`)?

Your answer don't have to be in detail. I need a direction to look into.

Answer (score 1):

You need all dns records you want to serve resolve to your ip-address.

If you use your isp's domain and they arn't already resolving all subdomains to your ip, you need to get your own domain name to use.

If you already have your own domain, it is resolved by a dns-server (like bind) somewhere. You need to configure it to resolve all subdomains you need to your ip.

Once the dns resolves correctly it is just a matter of configuring your webserver.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean the DNS system will find the address of `alpha.example.com` , and try to ask that host for IP address of `one.alpha.example.com`. My extremely simple experiment is when I `ping one.alpha.example.com` or `nslookup one.alpha.example.com`, I get no answer. (I will get an answer after setup a BIND?)

Comment: The answer is to add one.alpha.example.com to your DNS records.  If you are using BIND, then yes, you would set them up in bind - However if you are using your registrars DNS - which seems to be adviseable here - they will probably let you add it at no cost to the zone file for alpha.example.com.

Comment: Say I am `alpha.example.com`, someone `nslookup one.alpha.example.com`, will the DNS _attempt_ to ask me for an address?

Comment: @frozen-flame: No. DNS works like this; A computer needs to look up `one.alpha.example.com` and asks its default DNS server (A). (A) does not know the answer so it in turn asks a root DNS server for `.com` (B). (B) forwards the request to the DNS-server responsible for `example.com` (C). IF (C) has an A-record for `one.alpha.example.com` it will return the information. IF (C) instead has an NS-record for `alpha.example.com` it will further forward the request to that DNS-server (in this case it COULD be your instance of `bind`). IF (C) has no record the request will return a failure.

Comment: @MattiasÅslund: Thanks a lot. So I should ask the registar to server as DNS-server for *.alpha.example.com?